# CX_Freeze - Error while loading shared object from library.zip: not a directory

Tags: python, linux, cx-freeze, zip, cefpython

I am bundling a graphical application with cx_freeze for Ubuntu 14, and we added a dependency on cefpython3. I installed the package from `deb` file, and the software runs fine from command line (`python (name-of-program).pyw`).

I made sure the package was included adding

```
packages = ["cefpython3"]
```

to setup.py.
Then it complained it could not find

```
(path-to-folder)/library.zip/cefpython3/libcef.so
```

so I added that to the zip via

```
zip_includes=[("/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/cefpython3/libcef.so","cefpython3/libcef.so")
```

and now if I open `library.zip` I find `libcef.so` inside `cefpython3`, as it should.

But now when I run, it complains it is not a directory:

```
OSError: (path-to-folder)/library.zip/cefpython3/libcef.so: cannot open shared object file: Not a directory
```

I tried adding `libcef.so` otherwise via `bin_include` and even `include_files`, but it still tries to open it in `library.zip`, and just fails when it cannot.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe this post will be of help: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cefpython/ZCQWjutERHc/FlQElKAzmrkJ

Comment: It seems they just don't have my problem. Most of those files are only included under Windows, so the include_files would only contain a single "res" -which gives error if I include it. I tried adding the packages they list, but to no avail. I don't see what is the difference that makes their work and not mine. My best guess is they only use it in Macs.

Comment: I also tried adding optimize=2 and compressed=True, to no avail.